# QML Calendar not showing week day or month year (however it does seem to be there....)

Tags: qt, calendar, navigation, qml

I am using Qt 5.13 and in general Qt.Controls 2 however the calendar only exists in v1.0 or the labs version (which I can't get to work, so using V1).

My code is

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Old

import Tree 1.0
import "."

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 800; height: 1000
    title: "TreeView Example"
    visible: true
    Old.Calendar {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        id: calendar
    }
}
```

However when I do this, I don't see the day of the week, nor the month/year in the navivagation bar, although I can see where they should be:

[image: simple]

I have tried to add a navigationBar delegate, but this then gets rid of the navigation arrows.

```
style: CalendarStyle {
  navigationBar: Text {
    text: "hello"
  }
}
```

[image: nav bar]

So, how do I have the nav arrows, show the month/year and show the days of week? The documentation seems to suggest I would get these out of the box...
Now... I thought I could add drop downs as a work around to choose month/year and place them in the nav bar... however when I do that I can actually see that the days of the week are there, just their text colour is white, so I feel I am missing a trick with regard to the navigation bar...?

[image: drop downs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worth reading the comments in response to @Aleph0's post, but to get it working I had to copy the default styles and place them within my element. The final code (stripping out the bits that aren't specifically about the calendar then), looks like

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Old
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
  id: window
  width: 300; height: 300
  title: "Calendar Example"
  visible: true
  ColumnLayout {
      anchors.fill: parent
    Old.Calendar {
      id: calendar
      style: CalendarStyle {
          gridVisible: true
      dayOfWeekDelegate: Rectangle {
          color: gridVisible ? "#fcfcfc" : "transparent"
          implicitHeight: Math.round(TextSingleton.implicitHeight * 2.25)
          Label {
              text: control.locale.dayName(styleData.dayOfWeek, control.dayOfWeekFormat)
              anchors.centerIn: parent
          }
      }
        navigationBar: Rectangle {
          height: Math.round(TextSingleton.implicitHeight * 2.73)
          color: "#f9f9f9"

          Rectangle {
              color: Qt.rgba(1,1,1,0.6)
              height: 1
              width: parent.width
          }

          Rectangle {
              anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
              height: 1
              width: parent.width
              color: "#ddd"
          }

          HoverButton {
              id: previousMonth
              width: parent.height
              height: width
              anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
              anchors.left: parent.left
              source: "./assets/leftanglearrow.png"
              onClicked: control.showPreviousMonth()
          }
          Label {
              id: dateText
              text: styleData.title
              elide: Text.ElideRight
              horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
              font.pixelSize: TextSingleton.implicitHeight * 1.25
              anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
              anchors.left: previousMonth.right
              anchors.leftMargin: 2
              anchors.right: nextMonth.left
              anchors.rightMargin: 2
          }
          HoverButton {
              id: nextMonth
              width: parent.height
              height: width
              anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
              anchors.right: parent.right
              source: "./assets/rightanglearrow.png"
              onClicked: control.showNextMonth()
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That results in 
[image: calendar result]

In an ideal world, there would be an alternative to a) using `Private` controls as that seems like I am using Qt internal modules, but thats an easy fix by using an Image with a mouse area, and if I didn't have to use any 1.x controls either, but there doesn't seem to be a 2.x way of graphically displaying dates etc. Anyway, hopefully this can be useful to someone - it's literally a copy paste job of the default styling so it can be simplified alot...

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Qt 5.13.0 and just tried you example. After removing some imports it was working with the following files:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Old
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 800; height: 1000
    title: "TreeView Example"
    visible: true
    Old.Calendar {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        id: calendar
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();

    engine.load(QUrl("./data/main.qml"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

I'll obtain the following:

[image: Calender Application Snapshot]

I suggest, that you will try my code and compare it with your application.

Comment: Hmm, yes the same with your example I can't see the content of the nagivation bar (except the nav arrows) and I can't see the days of the weeks just like in mine

Comment: @amlwwalker: That is really odd. What is your operating system? Mine is Windows7. Maybe you can check your loaded modules with Process Explorer in case they wrong Dlls are loaded?

Comment: Hmm I'll do some more research, as calendar is deprecated what other methods are there to illustrate dates etc? Can I use styles to force the text colour of the nav bar etc to black without having to completely rebuild the nav bar?

Comment: OK the only way I could solve this was by copying the delegates out of the actual CalendarStyle.qml file and pasting them into my calendar component. I will add an answer so that others can benefit if needs be

Comment: @amlwwalker I'm really baffled, why there is no problem on my configuration. What is different in your settings. These are sometimes the hardest questions to answer. I'm really interested what you had to change, that it works on your machine. I suggest that you try your app also on a different machine than yours.

Comment: I'm pretty baffled too and as a result I don't really know where to look in terms of settings. I've posted an answer below which is basically just me copying the default settings out of the dyamically linked libraries from QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/CalendarStyle.qml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - days of week and title were almost invisible, because they were written with white color on light gray background. In my case the problem was in desktop color theme in Ubuntu Studio. After I changed it from Dark to Light the text appeared in black as expected. It seems Qt5 can't handle dark themes well or implementation in Ubuntu Studio (22.04) is buggy. The same was true for text in Button-s.